# chart.js - How to extend graph line to the edge of canvas (pictures)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am unable to find answer on how to extend both grid lines and graph line to the edge of the canvas and make it fill with background color, while keeping the padding and value ratio (pictures better show what I mean)

Currently, I have canvas as seen here:
[image: chart.js graph with padding]

and I want to achieve result as sampled here:
[image: chart.js graph with extended lines]

My current code:

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["PON", "WT", "ŚR", "CZW", "PT", "SB"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [56, 35, 35, 60, 20, 50],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,255,255)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,

            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointBorderColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(112,185,200,1.00)'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        layout: {
            padding: {
                top: 15,
                bottom: 35,
                left: 155
            }
        },

        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        scales: {
            color: 'rgb(255,255,255)',

            yAxes: [{

                position: 'right',
                 labelFontColor: "red",
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    fontColor: '#eee',
                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                    padding: 20
                },
                gridLines: {
                    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)',
                    drawBorder: false,
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                position: 'top',
                color: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: '#eee',
                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                    padding: 20
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, did you get the answer? I have the same problem

Comment: Hey, sadly, no :( When I think about it now, I guess it can be solved using JavaScript to generate SVG with parent container set to overflow: hidden. Lots of tinkering but can be done :)